# Use Imported modules in subshell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, import-module

is there a way to use imported modules in Powershell in subshell?

for example, if I load a module in my script (A) and then, inside it, I call another script(B), can I use loaded modules in the final script (B)?

Comment: are you calling the script with or without spawning a new instance of powershell ?

Comment: I call the second script using powershell.exe .\myscript.ps1

Comment: In that case you will have to re-import the module from inside script-b or make the module command part of one of your profiles so it gets pre-loaded for all instances of powershell.exe  -- confirm if that fixes and I will post as answer